# What is the correct type of the Berry curvature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, curvature, quantum-anomalies, hall-effect

I am studying Berry curvature for a specific material and faced different types of the Berry curvature formula. Some papers use only valence eigenstates (u1) like this $$i*(<(∂U1/∂kx)| (∂U1/∂ky)> − <(∂U1/∂ky)|(∂U1/∂kx)>)$$ and someone uses summation on all the conduction and valence bands like this $$i*(<(∂U1/∂kx)| (∂U2/∂ky)> − <(∂U1/∂ky)|(∂U2/∂kx)>).$$ I'm confused about which one should I use for my calculations.